# Can't open socket C++

Tags: c++, sockets, opencv, iplimage

I'm trying to send images (using IlpImage library) to VLan (media player) through the network so it can play streaming images and "make" a video.

I'm trying to open a socket but the value of "serversock" gives me always -1 and I don't understand why. I'm trying to search for this error but can't find a solution. Can someone help me?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
//#include <fstream>

//#include "Packet.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  // OpenCV window I/O

using namespace std;

#define PORT 8888
#define GROUP "127.0.0.1"

int serversock, clientsock;
int is_data_ready = 0;

//methods
void quit(char* msg, int retval);
void sendImg (IplImage *img);

void sendImg(IplImage *img) {

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int opt = 1;

    /* setup server's IP and port */
    memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(GROUP);
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

While debbuging the value of `serversock` should be 0 and it gets -1, not continuing with the program.

```
    if (serversock < 0) { // or == -1
        quit("socket() failed", 1);
    } //else {cout<< "Consegui!" << endl

    cout << "socket() succeeded" << endl;

    if(setsockopt(serversock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST, (const char*) &opt,sizeof(int))==-1){
        quit("setsockopt failed",0);
    }

    /*
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;*/

    /* bind the socket */
    if (bind(serversock, (const sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        quit("bind() failed", 1);
    }

    /* wait for connection */
    if (listen(serversock, 10) == -1) {
        quit("listen() failed.", 1);
    }

    /* accept a client */
    if ((clientsock = (int)accept(serversock, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
        quit("accept() failed", 1);
    }

    /* the size of the data to be sent */
    int imgsize = img->imageSize;
    int bytes=0;

    //start sending images
    if (is_data_ready) {
        is_data_ready = 0;
        if( (bytes = sendto(serversock, img->imageData, imgsize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) ) == -1) {
            quit("sendto FAILED", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`WSAGetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine the cause of the failure:

```
if (serversocket < 0)
{
    const DWORD last_error = WSAGetLastError();
    // Pass 'last_error' to either the 'quit' function
    // or log it somewhere else.
}
```

[`WSAStartup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not present in the posted code and it must be called before using any of the socket API functions.

Comment: Thanks hmjd, it worked for the opening of the socket but now I have another error here:

`if(setsockopt(serversock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST, (const char*) &opt,sizeof(int))==-1)
{
   wprintf(L"socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
   WSACleanup();
   quit("setsockopt failed",0);
}`

And the application tells me:
`socket failed with error: 10042`

I'm going to search what this error stands for.

Comment: It looks like a WSAENOPROTOOPT protocol error. I changed from `serversocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`to `serversocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)` and it worked :)